# How can I open a BIM viewer in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, bim

I tried to run a code snippet for a simple IFC viewer taken from the [apstex](https://www.apstex.com/info.html) website in Eclipse and I'm obviously lacking something for the 3D widget but I can't figure out for the life of me what I'm doing wrong. The setup worked and I can read and write models but I can't display them.

This is the code snippet from their website:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple IFC Viewer");
Widget3D widget = new Widget3D();
frame.add(widget);
```

The `Widget3D` can't be referenced, so I'm obviously missing some library or something but my googling didn't produce anything.
Am I lacking something because it's only the demo version? Do I need another API for this?

Comment: It would help the group here in answering your question if you share the code/link from where you took the code and explain what exactly you are trying to achieve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On the [apstex home page](http://www.apstex.com/) there is a list of features, which are actually implemented as separat packages. Of those packages, only *IFC Java Toolbox* (Full access to IFC-based BIM models) and demo versions of *IFC Java Viewer* (Java viewer for IFC models) and *IFC WebGL Viewer* (WebGL viewer for IFC models) are available from the download area for non-commercial use, after registering an account. All other components are available on request. Conditions are not disclosed, you have to contact apstex individually to get access to the full version.

The `Widget3D` class is likely in the *IFC Java GUI Components* package (Graphical user interface components). Without access to the package you can not import and instantiate the class.